# Sequelize throwing "Invalid value { searchTerm: 'Kaizer fc', sportType: '2' }" on Postman

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

Im trying to create a sequalized query that Searches For a Team Name & Filter To Sport Type but when I test the JSON body on Postman I get an error and its not returning the data. The JSON body matches the data that its meant to return but its not matching up.

Test on Postman

```
{
   "searchTerm": "Kaizer fc",
   "sportType": "2"
}
```

teams.js

```
const Teams = require('../models').teams;
const {sequelize, QueryTypes } = require('sequelize');
const db = require('../models')

const search = (searchTerm, sportType) => {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {     
      
        console.log("Testing");

        const teams = await db.sequelize.query(
          `SELECT teams.name, institutions.name, addresses.line1, addresses.line2, addresses.country 
           FROM teams
           INNER JOIN institutions
           ON teams.institution_id = institutions.id
           INNER JOIN addresses
           ON institutions.address_id = addresses.id
           WHERE teams.name like :search_name and teams.sport_type_id LIKE :sport_type`,
          {
            replacements: { search_name: searchTerm, sport_type: sportType },
            type: QueryTypes.SELECT
          }
        );

        return resolve(teams);
      } catch (err) {
        return reject(err)
      }
  })
}
```

teams.js - Models Folder

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const teams = sequelize.define('teams', {
        name: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
        media_id: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: true },
        state_id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, allowNull: true },
        status_id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, allowNull: true },
        sport_type_id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, allowNull: false },
        created_by: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, allowNull: true, references: { model: 'users', key: 'id' } },
        modified_by: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, allowNull: true, references: { model: 'users', key: 'id' } },
        primary_user_id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, allowNull: true, references: { model: 'users', key: 'id' } },
        institution_id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, allowNull: true, references: { model: 'institutions', key: 'id' } },
    }, {
        createdAt: 'created_at',
        updatedAt: 'updated_at',
        indexes: [
            {
                unique: true,
                fields: ['id']
            }
        ],
    });
    return teams;
};
```

search.js - Controllers

```
const helper = require('../utils/helper');
const teamsService = require('../services/teams');

const search = async (req, res) => {

    try {
        const data = await teamsService.search(req.body);

        console.log("TESTING");
        console.log(data);
        
        return res.send(data);

    } catch (err) {
        return helper.handleError(err, req, res);
    }
}

module.exports = search;
```

Comment: Show the content of `req.body`

Comment: The content of the req.body is {
   "name": "Kaizer fc",
   "sport_type_id": "2"
}

Comment: As an object? Or as a string?

Comment: Its an Object with a method of post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`search` function has two arguments: `searchTerm` and `sportType` and you pass the whole `req.body` as a first argument so that's why it becomes a value for `searchTerm` and you got this error about the whole value from Sequelize.
Just extract both props from `req.body` OR define `search` with props passed by as an object:

```js
const { searchTerm, sportType } = req.body;
const data = await teamsService.search(searchTerm, sportType);
```

OR

```js
const data = await teamsService.search(req.body);
...
const search = ({ searchTerm, sportType }) => {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
```

Comment: {
    "message": "Named parameter \":search_name\" has no value in the given object."
}

Comment: Check `searchTerm` indise `search` function

Comment: And what solution did you choose?